# Firebase Database REST API Increase Number

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
return Axios
 .put(URL/items/myItemId.json,tokenVoteAllTime:tokenVoteAllTime+1)
 .then(res => {
    console.log(res)
 })
```

Hi All. That codes my wrong codes. How can i update tokenVoteAllTime value in Firebase Project?

Exmple Structure:  `Coins/CoinID.tokenVoteAllTime:0`

Comment: If you want to increment a value in the Firebase Realtime Database, you would need to read the value, increment it in code and write it back out. Firestore offers an increment function. However, there's no code in the question that shows that process so we won't really know where the issue is. Please review the following two guide [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Jay: there is nowadays an `increment` operation in Realtime Database, which allows this as a single, atomic operation.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen WOW! That's awesome info. It's available in the client side SDK's as well.

Comment: Yup.  They were added early 2020 if I recall correct. Just in case you missed other Realtime Database API updates: it now also has a `getData()` call on iOS that fixes the caching peculiarities of `observeSingleEvent`, and there are `startAfter()` and `endBefore` methods to paginate without overlapping nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A server-side, atomic increment can be done with an [increment operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database#section-server-values).

In your case the value for your update would look something like this:

```
tokenVoteAllTime: { ".sv": {"increment": 1 }}
```